# Working with Java Script and multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

I am currently working on a website type project and I am new to JavaScript. So I have been having troubles with some parts of the syntax. Basically I am trying to print the 'id' and 'value' in the nested array arr.

```
var myArray = new Array({id:'1', value:'een', arr: new Array({id:'10', value:'een'})};
var obj = myArray[0];
document.write(obj.id);
```

this will print the id 1 but im not sure how to access id 10.

Also if there is an easier way to do this let me know please!

Comment: fyi, don't use `new Array()` but the `[]` array literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper reference would be:

```
obj.arr[0].id
```

PS:  google chrome developer console is a goot playground for testing javascript object dereefrecing

Comment: If i wanted to initialize an array like this of size 10 by 10 how would i do so?

Comment: I would propose [] literals for this purpose,  but it would be pretty werbose - but there is no way around.  Usually such javascript arrays come from server from some kind of AJAX service ( JSON is syntactially valud javascipt literal and can be just evaluated),  where they are converted automatically from some backend data model

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, don't use the `new Array` constructor. Just define an array literal `[...]`. So your `myArray` will look like:

```
var myArray = [{id:'1', value:'een', arr: [{id:'10', value:'een'}]}];
```

To get to the `id` of `10`, you need to access `myArray[0].arr[0].id;`.

Comment: `[0]`, not `[1]` for the inner array

Comment: Don't ask why I wrote `[1]`. I have no idea XD

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can't without iterating over the array.</strike>

If order does not matter, use an object instead:

```
var myObject = {
    1: {id:'1', value:'een'},
    10: {id:'10', value:'een'}
};
var obj = myArray[10];
document.write(obj.id);
```

In case the nesting in your array is intended, here's what you want:

```
var obj = myArray[0].arr[0];
```

Demo:

```
> var myArray = new Array({id:'1', value:'een', arr: new Array({id:'10', value:'een'})});
> myArray[0].arr[0]
{ id: '10', value: 'een' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would for get arrays why not create your own object ?

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: I would like to create an array of objects but i wasn't sure how to do so